# Using an adverbial phrase between the object and the participle?

Tags: sentence-construction, participles

> There's been ***a gentleman here asking for you***, sir.

As far as I know, In this form the participle always comes immediately after the object of the main clause.

After I saw this sentence above. A question came to my mind: Can I use an adverbial phrase between the object of the main clause and the participle clause? I think the question I quoted above does that.

For example:

> 1- I found ***him under the tree waiting*** for me.
>
> 2- I left ***my cat on my bed lying*** down.
>
> 3- Stream pushed ***the ducks along the riverside whistling*** to each
>   other. (In the meantime, the ducks were whistling to each other.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your examples is that each of those inserted phrases ends with a *noun* which precedes a participle clause and can combine with it, giving some false sense. With such a word order, an additional comma just after the noun could prevent from reading like: '*tree waiting for me*', '*my bed lying down*' and '*the riverside whistling*'.

Comment: Where should I put the comma? I think if I wrote this way "I found him, under the tree waiting for me." or "I found him under the tree, waiting for me" , it would be a dangling participle phrase.

Comment: Hmm I think this one works: " I found him ,under the tree, waiting for me.